# Decimal to Integer in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Remove the Decimal values

```
select cast(val as integer),val from table
```

and I tried round that is also not working pls tell me the way to solve this.

```
select ROUND(2.9,0) from dual

24  23.8331134259259
31  30.8322222222222
31  30.8321990740741
31  31.1120023148148
31  31.1119791666667
28  28.0590046296296
31  31.1177314814815
4   4.05344907407407
4   4.03957175925926
14  13.7137731481481
5   4.79490740740741
5   4.79490740740741
5   4.79489583333333
5   4.79488425925926
```

Expected Output :

```
23  23.8331134259259
30  30.8322222222222
30  30.8321990740741
30  31.1120023148148
30  31.1119791666667
28  28.0590046296296
31  31.1177314814815
4   4.05344907407407
4   4.03957175925926
13  13.7137731481481
4   4.79490740740741
4   4.79490740740741
4   4.79489583333333
4   4.79488425925926
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi try truncate function

```
TRUNC( number, [ decimal_places ] )
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [`FLOOR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions067.htm#SQLRF00643)?

> FLOOR returns the largest integer equal to or less than n. The number n can always be written as the sum of an integer k and a positive fraction f such that 0 <= f < 1 and n = k + f. The value of FLOOR is the integer k. Thus, the value of FLOOR is n itself if and only if n is precisely an integer.

Comment: @sunleo - yep, both `FLOOR` and `TRUNCATE` will work - we don't know which one you actually want until we see how you want to deal with negative numbers.

Comment: at any case there will be no negative values

Answer (score 1):

Just `select FLOOR(2.9,0) from dual`